# As a limited partner in an LLC, can my role be considered active?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, limited-liability-company, legal, passive-income

**I want to stay as a passive investor in an LLC for short term rental of Real Estate**

Is there anything in the schedule k-1 that might make me an active member instead ?

What kind of income is ok for passive investors on the k-1?

Any particulars to look out for in the operating agreement to this end ?

Comment: If the investor doesn't get a salary from the multi-member LLC then the investor is probably passive. Of course the IRS has several pages of rules. The passive investor is still accounted a percentage of the gains or losses but not subject to self-employment tax.

Answer (score 2):

Line 14 shows "self-employment earnings (loss)", that's the income that is attributed directly to *your performing personal services* for the LLC. Income reported on that line is similar to 1099-NEC income reported to a self-employed individual.

Regarding the operating agreements - consult your lawyer who's drafting it for you. It's a legal document.